# in log4net, is it possible to mute loggers by name rather than by level only?

Tags: log4net

I am building a new C# project using the DLLs produced by some colleagues.
They have log4net statements at all levels popping around in such number that my logs are hardly visible in the mass...

in log4net, is it possible to mute loggers by name rather than by level only ?
or even better, by assembly name ? I want to mute logging in DLLs that I use...

Thank you guys for any hints !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a matter of adding a section to your config file like

```
 <logger name="xxx" additivity="false">
     <level value="OFF" />
 </logger>
```

If logging is using the standard convention, ie

```
internal static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

then you need to replace xxx can be the namespace or part of the namespace that you want to disable.

If your colleagues are using the exact same namespace name as you are using,then you might need to replace xxx with the actual class name which could mean you end up with a large number of entries in your config file to disable logging for each of their classes.